# NullPointer Error for JSP connection on maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp

I am using Eclipse Maven Project to display data from Cassandra onto front end (using Tomcat framework, JSP). I am running into an issue when trying to display data onto webpage.

For servlet java file,

```
    @WebServlet("/test")
public class homeServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    //private homeDAO homedao;

          
      protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
                                    HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException
        {
         response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
         try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
           out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
           out.println("<html>");
           out.println("<head>");
           out.println("<title>Servlet StudentServlet</title>");
           out.println("</head>");
           out.println("<body>");
      
           // List to hold Post objects
           ArrayList<Post> post = new ArrayList<Post>();
      
           // Adding members to the list. Here we are 
           // using the parameterized constructor of 
           // class "Post.java"
           post.add(new Post("test","test", true));
           post.add(new Post("test","test", true));
           post.add(new Post("test","test", true));
           post.add(new Post("test","test", true));
           System.out.println(post.get(1));
           // Setting the attribute of the request object
           // which will be later fetched by a JSP page
             request.setAttribute("data", post);
      
           // Creating a RequestDispatcher object to dispatch
           // the request the request to another resource
             RequestDispatcher rd = 
                 request.getRequestDispatcher("test.jsp");
      
           // The request will be forwarded to the resource 
           // specified, here the resource is a JSP named,
           // "test.jsp"
              rd.forward(request, response);
                out.println("</body>");
                out.println("</html>");
            }
        }
        
    /*public void init() {
        homedao = new homeDAO();
    }*/

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                        HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
                        HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }
```

And then for the JSP file (test.jsp),

```
    <%@page import="home.homeModel.Post"%>
    <%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
    <%@page import="java.util.List" %>
    <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
       <title>Post List</title>
      </head>
      <body>
      <<form class="testpage" action="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/test" method="Post">
          <h1>Displaying Student List</h1>
          <table border ="1" width="500" align="center">
             <tr bgcolor="00FF7F">
              <th><b>User Name</b></th>
              <th><b>Post Description</b></th>
              <th><b>Adoptable</b></th>
             </tr>
           
            <%ArrayList<Post> post = 
                (ArrayList<Post>)request.getAttribute("data");
            for(Post s:post){%>
            
                <tr>
                    <td><%=s.getUsername()%></td>
                    <td><%=s.getDescription()%></td>
                    <td><%=s.isAdoptable()%></td>
                </tr>
                <%}%>
            </table> 
            <hr/>
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

When I execute and go to the webpage, it rotates between two errors, which both show core error being NullPointerException.
Error message:

```
    SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/adoptable.web] threw exception [An exception occurred processing [/test.jsp] at line [23]
    
    20:        
    21:         <%ArrayList<Post> post = 
    22:             (ArrayList<Post>)request.getAttribute("data");
    23:         for(Post s:post){%>
    24:         
    25:             <tr>
    26:                 <td><%=s.getUsername()%></td>
    
    
    Stacktrace:] with root cause
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.jsp.test_jsp._jspService(test_jsp.java:140)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:71)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:476)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
```

Could someone please help me on rooting this issue?

Comment: Find the generated code for test jsp, go to line 140, and see references appear on that line.  One of them is null.  FYI - JSPs are an old technology.  You shouldn't be using scriptlets in JSPs.  If you must use JSP, you should be using JSTL.  The world has moved on to REST services for back end and HTML, CSS, and JavaScript for the front end

Comment: @duffymo Plenty of projects still use JSP.  Sometimes simplicity is the best approach.  Sometimes an HTML template is all that’s needed.  Though I certainly agree that scriptlets should be avoided and JSTL should be used, since it’s practically part of the JSP specification.

Comment: I doubt very much that you have any data to support that.  Simplicity is indeed the best approach; hopelessly out of date is not.  JSP was a response to ASP.  Both are passe now.